# Using Celery to execute method on startup

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Currently, we are using Celery & RabbitMQ to perform repeatable tasks on Ubuntu 14.04 servers and everything is working great. Celery picks up tasks from RMQ and executes the correct method. We have 12 Celery workers constantly monitoring RMQ queues. We have a new requirement where we want to execute 1 method in Celery only once or say once a day. Is this possible to do? I don't want to look at possibly other technologies as we are invested in Celery/RMQ at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For every task, you can store a boolean value which will keep track whether that is executed for the day for not, this data you can store in db or some file store.
Maintain a cron that executes daily that sets every task value to false(assuming false as task not executed for that day).
Create a celery pre_run signal that will return if the task is already done for the day else continues task processing

```
from django.db import models

class TaskModel(models.Model)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_executed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


from celery.signals import task_prerun

@task_prerun.connect()
def task_setup(signal=None, sender=None, task_id=None, task=None, args=None, kwargs=None):
    # this method executes before every celery task
    task_obj = TaskModel.objects.get(task=task.name)
    if task_obj.is_executed:
        return
```

Comment: If I wanted to store a unique value per worker for the day, how would I go about doing that with Redis as the db? Since there are multiple celery workers, I want to store their key/id along with the value in Redis. This way, there is a one-to-one match and values are not shared.

Answer (score 0):

Celery beat is made exactly for this requirement: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html